# How do I get rid of these error messages ? (PyCharm)

Tags: python, console, message

Error Message

[image: 2]

Only appears when I encounter an error in my program, if there are none bugs/errord I don't see them in my console....

interpreter : [Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fv02.png)
PATH : [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSXVc.png)

Haven't tried anything yet, quite new to coding.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the error message as text into your question? That will make it easier for others to search for your question if they ever encounter a similar problem.

Comment: This is just the top of the stacktrace. Pycharm wraps your program via a different python program (`pydev`) to get easier access for debuggin. It's normal, just ignore them.